# Fit Path to SVG

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG from fontawesome, but there is space around the path content inside the SVG window.

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="youtube" class="svg-inline--fa fa-youtube fa-w-18" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
<path fill="currentColor" d="M549.655 124.083c-6.281-23.65-24.787-42.276-48.284-48.597C458.781 64 288 64 288 64S117.22 64 74.629 75.486c-23.497 6.322-42.003 24.947-48.284 48.597-11.412 42.867-11.412 132.305-11.412 132.305s0 89.438 11.412 132.305c6.281 23.65 24.787 41.5 48.284 47.821C117.22 448 288 448 288 448s170.78 0 213.371-11.486c23.497-6.321 42.003-24.171 48.284-47.821 11.412-42.867 11.412-132.305 11.412-132.305s0-89.438-11.412-132.305zm-317.51 213.508V175.185l142.739 81.205-142.739 81.201z"></path>
</svg>
```

How would I remove this space and have the path edges touch the SVG window?
CSS preferable but open to other solutions.

[image]

Comment: That's not the only code you must be having, because I tried and I don't see any spacing around, probably you are using `display: inline-block;` which usually throws in `4px` spacing horizontally on an inline element. Can't help you much until I see all your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002472/find-svg-viewbox-that-trim-whitespace-around

Comment: And for setting it through css there is https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/7 which hasn't moved much in a few years. So the only other CSS solution would be to scale your <path>, but that would require hard-coded values for every glyphs.

Comment: @Mr.Alien sorry had the wrong example code, svg updated to what you see in the image here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a CSS solution, but you can do it in JavaScript by setting the SVG's view box dimensions to those of the bounding box:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const {x, y, width, height} = svg.getBBox();

svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `${x} ${y} ${width} ${height}`);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="svg-inline--fa fa-instagram fa-w-14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
<path
fill="currentColor"
d="M224.1 141c-63.6 0-114.9 51.3-114.9 114.9s51.3 114.9 114.9 114.9S339 319.5 339 255.9 287.7 141 224.1 141zm0 189.6c-41.1 0-74.7-33.5-74.7-74.7s33.5-74.7 74.7-74.7 74.7 33.5 74.7 74.7-33.6 74.7-74.7 74.7zm146.4-194.3c0 14.9-12 26.8-26.8 26.8-14.9 0-26.8-12-26.8-26.8s12-26.8 26.8-26.8 26.8 12 26.8 26.8zm76.1 27.2c-1.7-35.9-9.9-67.7-36.2-93.9-26.2-26.2-58-34.4-93.9-36.2-37-2.1-147.9-2.1-184.9 0-35.8 1.7-67.6 9.9-93.9 36.1s-34.4 58-36.2 93.9c-2.1 37-2.1 147.9 0 184.9 1.7 35.9 9.9 67.7 36.2 93.9s58 34.4 93.9 36.2c37 2.1 147.9 2.1 184.9 0 35.9-1.7 67.7-9.9 93.9-36.2 26.2-26.2 34.4-58 36.2-93.9 2.1-37 2.1-147.8 0-184.8zM398.8 388c-7.8 19.6-22.9 34.7-42.6 42.6-29.5 11.7-99.5 9-132.1 9s-102.7 2.6-132.1-9c-19.6-7.8-34.7-22.9-42.6-42.6-11.7-29.5-9-99.5-9-132.1s-2.6-102.7 9-132.1c7.8-19.6 22.9-34.7 42.6-42.6 29.5-11.7 99.5-9 132.1-9s102.7-2.6 132.1 9c19.6 7.8 34.7 22.9 42.6 42.6 11.7 29.5 9 99.5 9 132.1s2.7 102.7-9 132.1z">
</path>
</svg>
```