# Modify "d" attribute of SVG path element to shift it 9 pixels to the left?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have some SVG code that displays the state of Alaska. Is there a way to modify the **d** attribute so that it shifts the path 9 pixels to the left? I would do it manually but it appears to be a very complex path command.

I don't want to offset the entire <svg> element.

Hopefully there is a way to do it programmatically, because I have 49 other states to modify as well.

Here's the SVG:

```
<svg width="959" height="593">
    <g class="state">
        <path id="AK" d="M161.1 453.7l-.3 85.4 1.6 1 3.1.2 1.5-1.1h2.6l.2 2.9 7 6.8.5 2.6 3.4-1.9.6-.2.3-3.1 1.5-1.6 1.1-.2 1.9-1.5 3.1 2.1.6 2.9 1.9 1.1 1.1 2.4 3.9 1.8 3.4 6 2.7 3.9 2.3 2.7 1.5 3.7 5 1.8 5.2 2.1 1 4.4.5 3.1-1 3.4-1.8 2.3-1.6-.8-1.5-3.1-2.7-1.5-1.8-1.1-.8.8 1.5 2.7.2 3.7-1.1.5-1.9-1.9-2.1-1.3.5 1.6 1.3 1.8-.8.8s-.8-.3-1.3-1c-.5-.6-2.1-3.4-2.1-3.4l-1-2.3s-.3 1.3-1 1c-.6-.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.5l1.8-1.9-1.5-1.5v-5h-.8l-.8 3.4-1.1.5-1-3.7-.6-3.7-.8-.5.3 5.7v1.1l-1.5-1.3-3.6-6-2.1-.5-.6-3.7-1.6-2.9-1.6-1.1v-2.3l2.1-1.3-.5-.3-2.6.6-3.4-2.4-2.6-2.9-4.8-2.6-4-2.6 1.3-3.2V542l-1.8 1.6-2.9 1.1-3.7-1.1-5.7-2.4h-5.5l-.6.5-6.5-3.9-2.1-.3-2.7-5.8-3.6.3-3.6 1.5.5 4.5 1.1-2.9 1 .3-1.5 4.4 3.2-2.7.6 1.6-3.9 4.4-1.3-.3-.5-1.9-1.3-.8-1.3 1.1-2.7-1.8-3.1 2.1-1.8 2.1-3.4 2.1-4.7-.2-.5-2.1 3.7-.6v-1.3l-2.3-.6 1-2.4 2.3-3.9v-1.8l.2-.8 4.4-2.3 1 1.3h2.7l-1.3-2.6-3.7-.3-5 2.7-2.4 3.4-1.8 2.6-1.1 2.3-4.2 1.5-3.1 2.6-.3 1.6 2.3 1 .8 2.1-2.7 3.2-6.5 4.2-7.8 4.2-2.1 1.1-5.3 1.1-5.3 2.3 1.8 1.3-1.5 1.5-.5 1.1-2.7-1-3.2.2-.8 2.3h-1l.3-2.4-3.6 1.3-2.9 1-3.4-1.3-2.9 1.9h-3.2l-2.1 1.3-1.6.8-2.1-.3-2.6-1.1-2.3.6-1 1-1.6-1.1v-1.9l3.1-1.3 6.3.6 4.4-1.6 2.1-2.1 2.9-.6 1.8-.8 2.7.2 1.6 1.3 1-.3 2.3-2.7 3.1-1 3.4-.6 1.3-.3.6.5h.8l1.3-3.7 4-1.5 1.9-3.7 2.3-4.5 1.6-1.5.3-2.6-1.6 1.3-3.4.6-.6-2.4-1.3-.3-1 1-.2 2.9-1.5-.2-1.5-5.8-1.3 1.3-1.1-.5-.3-1.9-4 .2-2.1 1.1-2.6-.3 1.5-1.5.5-2.6-.6-1.9 1.5-1 1.3-.2-.6-1.8v-4.4l-1-1-.8 1.5h-6.1l-1.5-1.3-.6-3.9-2.1-3.6v-1l2.1-.8.2-2.1 1.1-1.1-.8-.5-1.3.5-1.1-2.7 1-5 4.5-3.2 2.6-1.6 1.9-3.7 2.7-1.3 2.6 1.1.3 2.4 2.4-.3 3.2-2.4 1.6.6 1 .6h1.6l2.3-1.3.8-4.4s.3-2.9 1-3.4c.6-.5 1-1 1-1l-1.1-1.9-2.6.8-3.2.8-1.9-.5-3.6-1.8-5-.2-3.6-3.7.5-3.9.6-2.4-2.1-1.8-1.9-3.7.5-.8 6.8-.5h2.1l1 1h.6l-.2-1.6 3.9-.6 2.6.3 1.5 1.1-1.5 2.1-.5 1.5 2.7 1.6 5 1.8 1.8-1-2.3-4.4-1-3.2 1-.8-3.4-1.9-.5-1.1.5-1.6-.8-3.9-2.9-4.7-2.4-4.2 2.9-1.9h3.2l1.8.6 4.2-.2 3.7-3.6 1.1-3.1 3.7-2.4 1.6 1 2.7-.6 3.7-2.1 1.1-.2 1 .8 4.5-.2 2.7-3.1h1.1l3.6 2.4 1.9 2.1-.5 1.1.6 1.1 1.6-1.6 3.9.3.3 3.7 1.9 1.5 7.1.6 6.3 4.2 1.5-1 5.2 2.6 2.1-.6 1.9-.8 4.8 1.9zM46 482.6l2.1 5.3-.2 1-2.9-.3-1.8-4-1.8-1.5H39l-.2-2.6 1.8-2.4 1.1 2.4 1.5 1.5zm-2.6 33.5l3.7.8 3.7 1 .8 1-1.6 3.7-3.1-.2-3.4-3.6zM22.7 502l1.1 2.6 1.1 1.6-1.1.8-2.1-3.1V502zM9 575.1l3.4-2.3 3.4-1 2.6.3.5 1.6 1.9.5 1.9-1.9-.3-1.6 2.7-.6 2.9 2.6-1.1 1.8-4.4 1.1-2.7-.5-3.7-1.1-4.4 1.5-1.6.3zm48.9-4.5l1.6 1.9 2.1-1.6-1.5-1.3zm2.9 3l1.1-2.3 2.1.3-.8 1.9h-2.4zm23.6-1.9l1.5 1.8 1-1.1-.8-1.9zm8.8-12.5l1.1 5.8 2.9.8 5-2.9 4.4-2.6-1.6-2.4.5-2.4-2.1 1.3-2.9-.8 1.6-1.1 1.9.8 3.9-1.8.5-1.5-2.4-.8.8-1.9-2.7 1.9-4.7 3.6-4.8 2.9zm42.3-19.8l2.4-1.5-1-1.8-1.8 1z">
            <title>Alaska</title>
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What's stopping you from drawing it as is, but at 9px to whatever direction? Seems pointless to modify the svg when you have full control of where it is drawn ... Otherwise you could always *learn* SVG and write some code to transform it however you want to.

Comment: @GetSet I want the path elements to fit snugly inside the <svg> container element without have to offset the whole thing every time I use it

Comment: Then you should say that in your question.

Comment: If you really just want "the path elements to fit snugly inside the <svg> container element", then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002472/find-svg-viewbox-that-trim-whitespace-around But indeed, [edit] your question so it asks this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of touching the `<path>`, you can just apply transformations to your `<g>` (it's allowed to apply it to the `<path>` as well, but I felt like that tag was complicated enough as it is).
In this case you'll want [`translate(x y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Translate):

```
<svg width="959" height="593">
    <g class="state" transform="translate(-9 0)">
        <path id="AK" d="M161.1 453.7l-.3 85.4 1.6 1 3.1.2 1.5-1.1h2.6l.2 2.9 7 6.8.5 2.6 3.4-1.9.6-.2.3-3.1 1.5-1.6 1.1-.2 1.9-1.5 3.1 2.1.6 2.9 1.9 1.1 1.1 2.4 3.9 1.8 3.4 6 2.7 3.9 2.3 2.7 1.5 3.7 5 1.8 5.2 2.1 1 4.4.5 3.1-1 3.4-1.8 2.3-1.6-.8-1.5-3.1-2.7-1.5-1.8-1.1-.8.8 1.5 2.7.2 3.7-1.1.5-1.9-1.9-2.1-1.3.5 1.6 1.3 1.8-.8.8s-.8-.3-1.3-1c-.5-.6-2.1-3.4-2.1-3.4l-1-2.3s-.3 1.3-1 1c-.6-.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.5l1.8-1.9-1.5-1.5v-5h-.8l-.8 3.4-1.1.5-1-3.7-.6-3.7-.8-.5.3 5.7v1.1l-1.5-1.3-3.6-6-2.1-.5-.6-3.7-1.6-2.9-1.6-1.1v-2.3l2.1-1.3-.5-.3-2.6.6-3.4-2.4-2.6-2.9-4.8-2.6-4-2.6 1.3-3.2V542l-1.8 1.6-2.9 1.1-3.7-1.1-5.7-2.4h-5.5l-.6.5-6.5-3.9-2.1-.3-2.7-5.8-3.6.3-3.6 1.5.5 4.5 1.1-2.9 1 .3-1.5 4.4 3.2-2.7.6 1.6-3.9 4.4-1.3-.3-.5-1.9-1.3-.8-1.3 1.1-2.7-1.8-3.1 2.1-1.8 2.1-3.4 2.1-4.7-.2-.5-2.1 3.7-.6v-1.3l-2.3-.6 1-2.4 2.3-3.9v-1.8l.2-.8 4.4-2.3 1 1.3h2.7l-1.3-2.6-3.7-.3-5 2.7-2.4 3.4-1.8 2.6-1.1 2.3-4.2 1.5-3.1 2.6-.3 1.6 2.3 1 .8 2.1-2.7 3.2-6.5 4.2-7.8 4.2-2.1 1.1-5.3 1.1-5.3 2.3 1.8 1.3-1.5 1.5-.5 1.1-2.7-1-3.2.2-.8 2.3h-1l.3-2.4-3.6 1.3-2.9 1-3.4-1.3-2.9 1.9h-3.2l-2.1 1.3-1.6.8-2.1-.3-2.6-1.1-2.3.6-1 1-1.6-1.1v-1.9l3.1-1.3 6.3.6 4.4-1.6 2.1-2.1 2.9-.6 1.8-.8 2.7.2 1.6 1.3 1-.3 2.3-2.7 3.1-1 3.4-.6 1.3-.3.6.5h.8l1.3-3.7 4-1.5 1.9-3.7 2.3-4.5 1.6-1.5.3-2.6-1.6 1.3-3.4.6-.6-2.4-1.3-.3-1 1-.2 2.9-1.5-.2-1.5-5.8-1.3 1.3-1.1-.5-.3-1.9-4 .2-2.1 1.1-2.6-.3 1.5-1.5.5-2.6-.6-1.9 1.5-1 1.3-.2-.6-1.8v-4.4l-1-1-.8 1.5h-6.1l-1.5-1.3-.6-3.9-2.1-3.6v-1l2.1-.8.2-2.1 1.1-1.1-.8-.5-1.3.5-1.1-2.7 1-5 4.5-3.2 2.6-1.6 1.9-3.7 2.7-1.3 2.6 1.1.3 2.4 2.4-.3 3.2-2.4 1.6.6 1 .6h1.6l2.3-1.3.8-4.4s.3-2.9 1-3.4c.6-.5 1-1 1-1l-1.1-1.9-2.6.8-3.2.8-1.9-.5-3.6-1.8-5-.2-3.6-3.7.5-3.9.6-2.4-2.1-1.8-1.9-3.7.5-.8 6.8-.5h2.1l1 1h.6l-.2-1.6 3.9-.6 2.6.3 1.5 1.1-1.5 2.1-.5 1.5 2.7 1.6 5 1.8 1.8-1-2.3-4.4-1-3.2 1-.8-3.4-1.9-.5-1.1.5-1.6-.8-3.9-2.9-4.7-2.4-4.2 2.9-1.9h3.2l1.8.6 4.2-.2 3.7-3.6 1.1-3.1 3.7-2.4 1.6 1 2.7-.6 3.7-2.1 1.1-.2 1 .8 4.5-.2 2.7-3.1h1.1l3.6 2.4 1.9 2.1-.5 1.1.6 1.1 1.6-1.6 3.9.3.3 3.7 1.9 1.5 7.1.6 6.3 4.2 1.5-1 5.2 2.6 2.1-.6 1.9-.8 4.8 1.9zM46 482.6l2.1 5.3-.2 1-2.9-.3-1.8-4-1.8-1.5H39l-.2-2.6 1.8-2.4 1.1 2.4 1.5 1.5zm-2.6 33.5l3.7.8 3.7 1 .8 1-1.6 3.7-3.1-.2-3.4-3.6zM22.7 502l1.1 2.6 1.1 1.6-1.1.8-2.1-3.1V502zM9 575.1l3.4-2.3 3.4-1 2.6.3.5 1.6 1.9.5 1.9-1.9-.3-1.6 2.7-.6 2.9 2.6-1.1 1.8-4.4 1.1-2.7-.5-3.7-1.1-4.4 1.5-1.6.3zm48.9-4.5l1.6 1.9 2.1-1.6-1.5-1.3zm2.9 3l1.1-2.3 2.1.3-.8 1.9h-2.4zm23.6-1.9l1.5 1.8 1-1.1-.8-1.9zm8.8-12.5l1.1 5.8 2.9.8 5-2.9 4.4-2.6-1.6-2.4.5-2.4-2.1 1.3-2.9-.8 1.6-1.1 1.9.8 3.9-1.8.5-1.5-2.4-.8.8-1.9-2.7 1.9-4.7 3.6-4.8 2.9zm42.3-19.8l2.4-1.5-1-1.8-1.8 1z">
            <title>Alaska</title>
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```