# Remove the whitespace around an SVG in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am working in a React Project that displays a scientific instrument. My SVGs currently have whitespace around them so they are located correctly with the other pieces that make up the instrument. When a specific piece is clicked, a popup will appear that contains the SVG of that piece. However, the whitespace around that piece makes the popup SVG appears small and not centered. I need to find a way to remove this whitespace. [Live Demo](https://rastonlab.github.io/Virtual-FTIR-Spectrometer/).

I have found multiple ways to remove the whitespace ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knLbjc9a/4/) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002472/find-svg-viewbox-that-trim-whitespace-around))

I believe the primary issue is with my library approach and how I am using it. I am placing the SVG into an `<img>` tag and using the dictionary to cleanly access the file path.

I have struggled to implement a working version of `getBBox()` (from the two examples of removing whitespace). Unsure if this is because of React or my ignorance. The primary way I have tried to get the SVG is using `fetch()`. Possibly there is a way to do this in React cleaner that I am unaware of. I have thought about resorting to adding additional individual SVGs without the whitespace, but thought of trying an approach first that does not involve file duplication (plus the infinite scalability of SVGs makes me feel that would be even more redundant).

**Library: ([GitHub](https://github.com/RastonLab/Virtual-FTIR-Spectrometer/blob/main/src/Components/SVGLibrary.js))**

```
import frm from './svgs/flat-rotatable-mirror.svg';
import globar from './svgs/globar.svg';
import pm from './svgs/parabolic-mirror.svg';
import tungsten from './svgs/tungsten.svg';
import sample from './svgs/sample-compartment.svg';
import dcfrm from './svgs/dc-flat-rotatable-mirror.svg';
import MCT from './svgs/MCT.svg';
import lnsb from './svgs/lnsb.svg';
import cdfrm2 from './svgs/cd-flat-rotatable-mirror-2.svg';
import fc from './svgs/fixed-corner-cube.svg';
import fm from './svgs/fixed-mirror.svg';
import laser from './svgs/laser.svg';
import mc from './svgs/movable-corner-cube.svg';
import pmh from './svgs/parabolic-mirror-w-hole.svg';
import pmh2 from './svgs/parabolic-mirror-w-hole-2.svg';

export const ttImgSrc = {
    'aperturewheel': wheel,
    'flatrotatablemirror': frm,
    'globar': globar,
    'parabolicmirror': pm,
    'tungsten': tungsten,
    'cdflatrotatablemirror': dcfrm,
    'samplecompartment': sample,
    'mct': MCT,
    'lnsb': lnsb,
    'cdflatrotatablemirror2': cdfrm2,
    'fixedcornercube': fc,
    'fixedmirror': fm,
    'laser': laser,
    'movablecornercube': mc,
    'parabolicmirrorhole': pmh,
    'parabolicmirrorhole2': pmh2,
}
```

**Popup Component ([GitHub](https://github.com/RastonLab/Virtual-FTIR-Spectrometer/blob/main/src/Components/SVGComponents.jsx)):**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ftirParts, toolTips, ttImgSrc } from "./SVGLibrary";
import { Dialog } from "@mui/material";
import "../style/SVGComponents.css";
import "../style/Popup.css";

export default function SVGComponent({ part, click }) {
  // Style is the intial stroke
  const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggled(!toggled);
  };

  const Component = ftirParts[part];

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <Component
        viewBox="-75 -0.5 418 212"
        className="svg"
        onClick={click ?? handleClick}
      />
      <Dialog className="popup" onClose={handleClick} open={toggled}>
        <h2>{toolTips[part].title}</h2>
        <img
          src={ttImgSrc[part]}
          id={`${part}-example-image`}
          className="example-image"
          alt=""
        />
        <p>{toolTips[part].text}</p>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

Popup sample:
[image: sample popup from the program]

Comment: Apparently you have 20 svg elements stacked one over another. You may try to change the viewBox attribute of **all of them** to viewBox="0 -0.5 264 212"

Comment: @enxaneta That is by design. We found it difficult to select individual pieces when all are placed into a single SVG file.

Comment: I see in your code that the <component> has a viewBox. change it to "0 -0.5 264 212"

Comment: @enxaneta That removes the extra whitespace around the main instrument. When a piece of the instrument is clicked, the extra whitespace still exists. I edited the original post to include a photo of what I am describing.